# perl sequence extraction loop

Tags: perl, shell, bioinformatics, fasta

I have an existing perl one-liner (from the Edwards lab) that works wonderfully to read a text file (named `ids.file`) that contains *one* column of IDs and searches a second, specially formatted text file (named `fasta.file` in this example - in "fasta" format for those who know bioinformatics) and returns sequences that match the ID from the first file. I was hoping to expand this script to do two additional things:

1. The current perl one-liner *only* seems to work if the `ids.file` contains one column of data. I would like it to work on a file that contains two columns (separated by spaces), and act on the second column of data (well, really any column of data, but I assume that it will be obvious enough to adapt it if someone can give an example using a second column)
2. I would like to append the any results returned from the output of the search to a third column, instead of just to a new file.

If someone is kind enough to offer an example but only has time or inclination to work on one of these, I would prefer that you try to solve #2 - I have come close to solving #1 with a for loop that uses awk to only use the Perl code on the second column - I haven't gotten it yet, but am close, so #2 seems like the harder one to me.

The perl one liner is as follows:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^>(\S+)/){$c=$i{$1}}$c?print:chomp;$i{$_}=1 if @ARGV' ids.file fasta.file
```

I appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: One sample input and output says more than three paragraphs of text. And is much easier to read.

Comment: I agree fully. Please add an example.

Comment: Sorry - here is a sample of the two input files: file ids.file looks like this: 
dog chevy
bear kia  
cat ford

and file fasta.file looks like this:

>chevy 334 3434 5 232 TGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGGAGAGAGAGAGGAGAGAG
>kia 2223 2323 23 ACACACACACACACACACC


The desired output is a script that searches fasta.file using column 2 from ids.file and creates an output file  that looks like this:

dog chevy >chevy 334 3434 5 232 TGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGGAGAGAGAGAGGAGAGAG
bear kia  >kia 2223 2323 23 ACACACACACACACACACC
cat ford

Comment: The script that perreal provides below does work, but doesn't seem to retain the columns that make it easily parsable by awk  , For example, running awk ' {print $3}' on the file will only return one result, not all  of them. In the example above, it would return    >chevy 334 3434 5 232 TGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGGAGAGAGAGAGGAGAGAG

Thanks!

@perreal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure but will this do?

```
perl -ne 'chomp; s/^>(\S+).*/$c=$i{$1}/e; print if $c; 
    $i{(/^\S*\s(\S*)$/)[0]}="$_ " if @ARGV' 
  ids.file fasta.file
```

Comment: Dearest "Perreal," it does indeed to appear to work! There are some sequences that have different amount of spacing between them (it appears to be inconsistent in how much space separates one set of three items from the next), but that just might be the way things are displaying on my screen. I'll move it to a CSV file and that should help. Thank you SO much!